# Why the non-symmetric design of rocket nozzles?

Tags: rockets, propulsion, engine-design, engines, nozzle

Although I have seen many perfectly symmetric nozzles, I have also seen designs such as this (Virgin Galactic) which is only symmetrical about one axis:

[image: Virgin Galactic SpaceShipTwo]

Why is this?

Comment: Sorry I mean the Falcon yes.

Answer (score 15):

According to comments on [this thread](http://www.parabolicarc.com/2014/01/12/spaceshiptwo-powered-flight-3-photo-essay/), the shape of the nozzle on SpaceShip Two is to provide "free pitch-up" during the short powered flight period. That nozzle shape would direct thrust force downward slightly, under the craft's center of gravity, causing it to slowly rotate nose-upward. Presumably modifying the nozzle shape was easier than tilting the whole engine, and the nozzle can be customized for different flight profiles (i.e. more or less fuel carried on a particular flight).

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RwHN50s1yw), you can see the pitch-up maneuver during the powered burn from roughly 0:30 to 1:00. Ordinary aircraft achieve pitch-up by using control surfaces (elevators/elevons), but using these creates drag. Directing the rocket motor thrust instead gives a pitching force, with less drag.

Comment: Just a note that the Falcon 9 v1.0 used 3x3 engine layout on the photo and that isn't the configuration they're flying now on Falcon 9 v1.1 that is using a _petal_ layout with 1 central engine and remaining 8 in a circle around it. Nozzles [still seem axially symmetric](http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/falcon-9-v1.1-new-engine-layout.jpg) to me tho, so this doesn't change anything for the answer.