# Are there rocket nozzles that use non-elliptical shapes?

Tags: nozzle

I was reading this question: [Why the non-symmetric design of rocket nozzles?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5347/why-the-non-symmetric-design-of-rocket-nozzles)

Which got me thinking, have there been any nozzles that don't end in an ellipse? Even the one in that question ends in a conic section, which is an ellipse. Perhaps maybe a notched ellipse, or a square? I realize that these are impractical for various reasons, but I don't doubt somebody has done experiments with non-elliptical nozzles.

---

**A couple short-comings I would assume with non-elliptical nozzles would be:**

- Potentially difficult (impossible?) gimbal.
- Incorrectly vectored thrust.
- Less concentrated thrust (possibly?).

(Feel free to correct/add to any of the above assumptions, because they are indeed assumptions).

---

If the answer is no, can someone give a quick-and-dirty why about the elliptical shape of all nozzles compared to something like a square?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [aerospike engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerospike_engine) don't have to be elliptical, since their "nozzle boundary" is just a line of equal pressure.

[image]

Even the little nozzles at the top of the ramp appear to be rectangular.

[image]

As far as why normal nozzles are circular, it allows for a nice smooth expansion. Flow in ducts with corners has a lot of nonuniformities.

[image]
[image]

The author states in reference to the secondary velocities

> Maximum velocities about 1 1/2 percent of the axial centerline
>   velocity occur along the walls near the corner. Along the
>   diagonal they reach 1 percent. Near the center of the duct the
>   secondary velocities are very small.

[Source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&ved=2ahUKEwjt2LDQ5KHeAhUH6oMKHV0lBv4QFjALegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdspace.mit.edu%2Fbitstream%2Fhandle%2F1721.1%2F44470%2F33309384-MIT.pdf%3Fsequence%3D2&usg=AOvVaw2o7RUICdF_0AHwlzWHAaLe)

A bit of explanation

> In a circular cross section tube the speed of material through the
>   tube is lowest near the sides due to drag. The speed increases as you
>   move away from the edges with highest speeds in the center. This
>   results in a parabolic speed profile. Now in a square tube the regions
>   near a corner are influenced by 2 sides so the speed will be even
>   slower there. As you move away from the sides a speed profile much
>   like a circular tube will develop. What you will end up with is that
>   the majority of the material will be flowing in a circular region
>   inside the square. The conclusion would be why pay for and carry
>   around the corners, they do not flow nearly as much flow as the center
>   region.

[Reference](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/air-flow-differance-square-versus-round-tubing.545502/)

Comment: Could you explain what the last picture actually represents? It looks really cool and I want to understand it. Also the link you gave is behind a paywall.

Comment: @Ingolifs [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.07699) appears to be the one that OrganicMarble linked to (or at rather a pre-print version of it).

Comment: @Ingolifs rewrote to use a non-paywalled paper and add some explication.